# Typescript Generics: How to reference both a class definition and instance type

Tags: typescript, generics

Sorry if this has been covered already, but my vocabulary is failing me :(

I'm trying to write a "collection" class, where at instantiation - I give it a "Model" class definition. The collection instance needs to be able to stamp out instances of "Model", but also needs to be able to call static methods on that class.

```js
type Ctor<T> = new (...args: any[]) => T

class Model<T> {
  foo: string
  bar: string
  static myMethod() {}
}

class Extension extends Model<Extension> {
  foobar() {}
}

Extension.myMethod() // works
const e = new Extension()

e.foobar() // works

class Collection<T> {
  public model: T

  constructor(model: T) {
    this.model = model
  }

  getModelInstance() {
    // clearly this is problematic
    const Model = this.model as unknown as Ctor<T> 
    return new Model()
  }
}
```

Now the problem becomes when I try to use it:

```js
const c = new Collection(Extension)
c.model.myMethod() // works

const m = c.getModelInstance()
m.foobar() // works at runtime, TS compiler says 'Property 'foobar' does not exist on type 'typeof Extension'.'
```

So I can redefine my constructor/instance definitions a bit:

```js
class Collection<T> {
  public model: Ctor<T>

  constructor(model: Ctor<T>) {
    this.model = model
  }

  getModelInstance() {
    const Model = this.model
    return new Model()
  }
}
```

```js
const c = new Collection(Extension)
c.model.myMethod() // Property 'myMethod' does not exist on type 'Ctor<Extension>'.

const m = c.getModelInstance()
m.foobar() // works
```

However this doesn't work because `Ctor` drops my static "context".

Is this possible? It seems like either form I lose type information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am fairly sure this will work for you. The relevant changes are to the `MyCollection` class and the use of `InstanceType`. Here it is [in the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Model%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20foo%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bar%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20static%20myStaticMethod()%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Extension%20extends%20Model%3CExtension%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20myInstanceMethod()%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0AExtension.myStaticMethod()%3B%0D%0Aconst%20e%20%3D%20new%20Extension()%3B%0D%0Ae.myInstanceMethod()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20MyCollection%3CTConstructor%20extends%20new%20()%20%3D%3E%20InstanceType%3CTConstructor%3E%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20modelConstructor%3A%20TConstructor%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(modelConstructor%3A%20TConstructor)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.modelConstructor%20%3D%20modelConstructor%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20getModelInstance()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20new%20this.modelConstructor()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20collection%20%3D%20new%20MyCollection(Extension)%0D%0Acollection.modelConstructor.myStaticMethod()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20model%20%3D%20collection.getModelInstance()%3B%0D%0Amodel.myInstanceMethod()%3B%0D%0A).

```
class Model<T> {
    foo: string;
    bar: string;
    static myStaticMethod() { }
}

class Extension extends Model<Extension> {
    myInstanceMethod() { }
}

Extension.myStaticMethod();
const e = new Extension();
e.myInstanceMethod();

class MyCollection<TConstructor extends new () => InstanceType<TConstructor>> {
    public modelConstructor: TConstructor

    constructor(modelConstructor: TConstructor) {
        this.modelConstructor = modelConstructor
    }

    getModelInstance() {
        return new this.modelConstructor();
    }
}

const collection = new MyCollection(Extension)
collection.modelConstructor.myStaticMethod();

const model = collection.getModelInstance();
model.myInstanceMethod();
```

Comment:  thank you very much! I missed the InstanceType stuff in the docs. I wish there were an API reference.

Comment: One problem I did have was that inside of `getModelInstance()`, we do not have access to any of the type defined on the base Model. Makes sense, the concrete types of `Extension` would not be available until you have an instance of Collection. I was able to get around this by defining getModelInstance method like so:

`const M = this.modelConstructor as unknown as typeof Model`
`return new M() as InstanceType<T>`

Dirty, but it works.

Comment: @JonJaques Brute force for the win!